# Strange writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, alassetslibrary, alasset

We have **"video-replated"** app and using `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:` from `ALAssetsLibrary` to save videos into camera roll. Most of the time it works very well, but sometimes `completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)` called with BOTH parameters `equal` to `nil`.

Documentation states that in case error is nil - no error occurred during write operation, so `assetURL` should not be `nil`. But still we get `assetURL == nil` and `error == nil` at the same time, sometimes

In what cases this is possible? Any help welcome.

Comment: possibly this happens when storage is full (i cannot validate this statement though). Anyway error should not be nil in this case, "not enough space" is quite regular situation, imho...

Comment: Does it occur on any device (iPhone? iPad) with iOS 8 ?

Comment: Yes, we have seen this on ios8 devices too

Comment: New data: this happens event when there is plenty of free space on device // Reasons still unknown

Comment: @IPv6 I am facing same issue, did you find any solution ?

Comment: seems like apple bug. I already filed Radar and see some similar radar bugs, confirmed by apple